# How to mock the “HttpRequestMessage” in Controller using NUnittest cases

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, nunit

**My Controller class:**

```
public class EodController : ApiControllerBase
{
    private readonly IEodManager eodManager;
    
    public EodController(IEodManager eodManager)
    {
        this.eodManager = eodManager;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetCheckAsync([FromUri] DateTime executionDate)
    {
        try
        {
            int Status = await this.eodManager.GetStatus(executionDate);

            var response = this.Request.CreateResponse(); **// It failed Here "this.Request" will be always NULL value**

            response.StatusCode = (Status == 1) ? HttpStatusCode.OK : (HttpStatusCode)207;

            response.Content =
                new PushStreamContent(
                    (stream, httpContext, transportContext) => this.eodManager.WriteToStream(stream, criteria, Status),
                    "application/json");

            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw this.ConstructHttpResponseException(string.Format("Execution Date: {0}.", executionDate), ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**I have Tried following things from test Class, it did not work .**

```
 public async Task ShouldReturnOKStatus()
        {
            // Arrange
            // Set up the mock
            var EodManager = new Mock<IEodManager>();
            DateTime executionDate = new DateTime(2023, 06, 27);

            var data = "this will be JSON";
            var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage();

            httpRequestMessage.Content= new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var command = new EodController(EodManager.Object);          // Act
            var response = await command.GetCheckAsync(executionDate);
            Assert.AreEqual("System.Web.Http.Results.OkResult", response.ToString());
              }
```

**Please let me know How do I Mock my HttpRequestMessage object so that when I my code flows traverse from nUnitTest it should not having NULL value for "this.Request.CreateResponse()".**